# Click on browser's back button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My main component Portal.js is as follows :

```
class Portal extends React.Component {
render() {
    const language = this.props.currentLanguage.default;
    const allShowrooms = data.getAllLists();

    return (
        <div className="mainPortal">
            <Navigation type="status" />
            <Showrooms allLists={allShowrooms} language={language}/>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

When this page loads `allShowrooms` is as follows:

```
allShowrooms = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "All brands stock sale mei",
        expires: "Sat Oktober 01 2016 15:58:59 GMT+0200",
        type: "Fixed"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "List number Two",
        expires: "Sat November 05 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0200",
        type: "Fixed"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "List number Three",
        expires: "Tue November 29 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0200",
        type: "Unfixed"
    }
]
```

When I click on one of the links in the navigation it goes to the new page. That works fine.

The problem is when I click on back in my browser, to go back to Portal. Then `allShowrooms` is changed to :

```
[
{
  "id":3,
  "name":"All brands stock sale mei",
  "expires":"Sat Oktober 01 2016 15:58:59 GMT+0200",
  "type":"Fixed"
},
{
  "id":3,
  "name":"List number Two",
  "expires":"Sat November 05 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0200",
  "type":"Fixed"
},
{
  "id":3,
  "name":"List number Three",
  "expires":"Tue November 29 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0200",
  "type":"Unfixed"
}
]
```

Thus, the ID for all lists inside `allShowrooms` is changed to 3. Why??

And then I have problem when I show photos, and the values in the circles, because I get those values via list id. I now, for all lists I have values of the list with id 3.

When I refresh the page, everything is ok.

Any advice?

**Update**

Data file (from where I get allShowroom = data.getAllLists())

```
    let allLists = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "All brands stock sale mei",
        expires: "Sat Oktober 01 2016 15:58:59 GMT+0200",
        type: "Fixed"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "List number Two",
        expires: "Sat November 05 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0200",
        type: "Fixed"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "List number Three",
        expires: "Tue November 29 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0200",
        type: "Unfixed"
    }
];


export function getAllLists(){
    return allLists;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Showrooms component is as follows :

```
render(){
    const language = this.props.currentLanguage;
    return (
       <div>
         {this.props.allLists.map( (list, i) =>  <View key={i} list={list} language={language}/>)}
      </div>
   )
}
```

And View component is as follows :

```
render (){
    const list = this.props.list;
    const url = list.id;
    const remainingTime = this.props.remainingTime;
    const language = this.props.language;

    return (
        <div className="block">
            <div className="listName">{list.name}</div>
            <div className="listBody">

                                <div className="counter"> {remainingTime.days} days     {remainingTime).hours} : {remainingTime.minutes} : {remainingTime.seconds}</div>

                                <Circles language={language} list={list} />

                                <Status list={list}/>
                        </div>
                        <Link to={`/showroom/${url}/`}>{language.portal.openShowroom}</Link>
         </div>
    )
  }
```

And then Circles component

```
render(){
    let {list, language} = this.props;
    const allCars = data.getAllCars(); //We get list of all cars
    const cars = carData.getCarsInCurrentList(list.id, allCars); //We get all cars, but only from this list
    const totalCarsInTheList = cars.length;
    const statusTotalCars = data.getUserOnGoingStatus().filter(s => s.listID === list.id && s.userID === userInfo.getUserEmail()).length;

    return (
        <div className="circles-box">
            <div className="circle-left">
                <div className="circle-content">
                    <div className="circle-total-cars">{totalCarsInTheList}</div>
                    <div className="circle-subtitle">{language.portal.nrCars}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="circle-right">
                <div className="circle-content">
                    <div className="circle-total-cars">{statusTotalCars}</div>
                    <div className="circle-subtitle">{language.portal.status}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Well this is a lot of code to go through. Please makes example so small as possible where it still does not work. This way more people will look at you question. You make effort, we make effort

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: I changed it a little bit. Is better now?

Comment: Maybe it is something to do with the `ShowRooms` component, you should include its code too

Comment: You need to give information on the 'data.getAllLists()' call, otherwise theres no clue for this issue :)

Comment: @Ash I updated my question.

Comment: Then as Khang statued, something happends in your Showroom component that modifies the id of the elements :)

Comment: @Ash I updated my question. But there is pretty much code :)

Answer (score 0):

if `data.getAllLists();`is synchronous stuff you can do something like this. Avoid logic in your render, it has to be more pure as possible.

```
class Portal extends React.Component {
 constructor (props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.allShowrooms = data.getAllLists();
  this.language = props.currentLanguage.default;
 }
 render() {

  return (
    <div className="mainPortal">
        <Navigation type="status" />
        <Showrooms allLists={this.allShowrooms} language={this.language}/>
    </div>
  );
 }
})
```

Comment: what this does? `data.getAllLists())``

Comment: I import it from a separate file `import * as data from '../../API/data';` and then I call a function `getAllLists()` which is in the data file. Data file is in the question.

Comment: is it a react-native app?

Comment: No. It's react js.

Comment: anyway maybe it's a type in show room you passing in you map the `language` but actually it should be `this.props.language`

Comment: There is `const language = this.props.currentLanguage;` inside render.